# Boehm GC android sigsegv on load_gc

Tags: c, android-ndk, boehm-gc

I'm having an odd crash in Boehm on Android x86 (but arm works fine); It's crashing on:

```
deferred = *(word *)limit;
```

with:

> LogCat: I/DEBUG   ( 6453): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0xa31f8

It's always the same address (0xa31f8) it fails at; Now this is probably something I'm doing wrong. This is a custom language and I'm just linking to libc.so. What could possibly cause this?

Log:

> LogCat: I/BDWGC   ( 7930): Grow heap to 64 KiB after 0 bytes allocated
>
> LogCat: D/BDWGC   ( 7930): Creating thread 0xb7795160
>
> LogCat: D/BDWGC   ( 7930): Stopping the world from 0xb7795160
>
> LogCat: D/BDWGC   ( 7930): World stopped from 0xb7795160
>
> LogCat: D/BDWGC   ( 7930): Pushing stacks from thread 0xb7795160
>
> LogCat: D/BDWGC   ( 7930): Stack for thread 0xb7795160 =
>    [0xbf90be1c,0xbf90f000) 
>   LogCat: F/libc    ( 7930): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xa31f8 in tid 7930 (ksample.oxygene)

Backtrace:

> (gdb) bt
>
> #0  0xa502c9ad in GC_mark_from (mark_stack_top=0xb8b30010, mark_stack=0xb8b30000, mark_stack_limit=0xb8b38000) at mark.c:853
>
> #1  0xa502c1d0 in GC_mark_some (cold_gc_frame=0xbf90beec "l¿\220¿Hò\001¥ì¾\220¿") at mark.c:409
>
> #2  0xa501f248 in GC_stopped_mark (stop_func=0xa501e420 ) at alloc.c:702
>
> #3  0xa501eed2 in GC_try_to_collect_inner (stop_func=0xa501e420 ) at alloc.c:488
>
> #4  0xa50254ff in GC_init () at misc.c:1288

Comment: "What could possibly cause this?" Heap corruption? There isn't nearly enough info in this question to give a useful answer.

Comment: @Thomas sorry about that, this is a boehm specific question.

Comment: But maybe it does not have a Boehm specific answer. If something, somewhere corrupted some memory that Boehm was using... boom. The "something, somewhere" could be in Boehm code (in which case it's a bug) but it might be in your own code, or in some other library you're using.

Comment: It happens on the entrypoint of boehm (calling GC_init), but it's possible I'm not implementing a dependent api properly yes, hence my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in boehm-gc for Android causing registration of a data root with an unmapped memory region (thus resulting in a SIGSEGV/SEGV_MAPERR during GC initialization).
Now it is [fixed](https://github.com/ivmai/bdwgc/issues/259).

Comment: Thanls! that did it combined with  -mstackrealign (see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37119345)